# How do I create a morphing effect from one shape to another?

Tags: javafx-2

The javafx 1.3 tutorial describes [how to morph a rectangle to a circle ?](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/howto/Shapes-Tutorial.html#morph).

[image]

The code is clear and very ... simple.

Is there an equivalent transformation in javafx 2.2 ?

Comment: Hi @gontard. Could you please take a look at my question, "[Is it possible to create a Stage in JavaFx whose height changes dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360919/how-to-dynamically-change-the-height-of-a-stage-in-javafx)", and see if you can hopefully help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awaiting a better solution, i have found a work-around.

My solution is based on a morphing algorithm available in the jfxrt.jar (`com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.ShapeEvaluator`) and on the method `javafx.scene.shape.Shape#createFromGeomShape`. Since these portions of code are not visible, i copied them.

The code is available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gontard/5029764).

Answer (score 1):

According to existing javadoc, and the Feature description :

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-11089

there is no such transformation, supported by JavaFX 2.2.

At current moment, that feature has no fix version, so, it is not planned to appear in JavaFX 8 (at least, at this moment). Possibly, it will appear in the future.

BTW, you can vote that feature up. If it has a high priority, it will more likely be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, where is the reference to the jira in the javadoc ?

Comment: I mean, javadoc contains no description of any similar functionality, and there a feature issue on such functionality, so, we can think, that it is not directly supported. Except that, usually javadoc doesn't describe possible fucntionality. (also, there are hundreds, if not thousands features, tweaks and RFEs, and they are not described in javadoc)

Comment: Sorry, i misread your answer. Sure, the javadoc doesn't reference all the potential features. Did you know if javafx 1.3 was open source ? May be i can migrate the source code.

Comment: Well, tough. thanks again Alexander. +1 for all your responses.

Comment: Hi @Alexander Kirov. Could you please take a look at my question, "[Is it possible to create a Stage in JavaFx whose height changes dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360919/how-to-dynamically-change-the-height-of-a-stage-in-javafx)", and see if you can hopefully help?