# How to dynamically change the height of a stage in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, stage

Is it possible to create a Stage in JavaFx whose height changes dynamically? Or, in other words, is it possible to change the height of a Stage once it has been created (`stage.show()`), so that the stage morph's into its new height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [stage.sizeToScene()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--) to resize the stage to whatever the current preferred size of it's root is.

```
 stage.setScene(new Scene(someContent));
 stage.show();
 ....
 stage.getScene().setRoot(someNewContent));
 stage.sizeToScene();
```

You can also just call [stage.setWidth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--) or stage.setHeight() if you don't need the automatic sizing behavior of `sizeToScene()`.

You can use a [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) to animate the stage size change if you need to do that.