# Java2D - morph/interpolate two Shapes

Tags: java, computational-geometry, java-2d

Is there some way - a library or an algorithm - that can be used to interpolate between two instances of `java.awt.Shape`, or its path iterators? For example, to transition seamlessly between a rectangle and an ellipse? Or the more general case of a `Path2D`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913303/how-do-i-create-a-morphing-effect-from-one-shape-to-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is a class `Morphing2D` in the [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) project. My preliminary testing shows, however, that it is restricted to shapes that do not contain `SEG_MOVETO` elements, and also that it doesn't do any fancy alignment between the two shapes, so the transition is not always ideal.
2. There is a software ReportMill that contains a [Morphing2D](http://www.reportmill.com/snap1/javadoc/com/reportmill/shape/RMMorphShape.Morphing2D.html). After investigation that company illegally copied the original SwingX code and pasted it into their closed source proprietary product. (An LGPL violation was filed with GNU)
3. I found [an example](https://gist.github.com/gontard/5029764) for JavaFX that seems to support move-to commands. This might have been included in JFX 1.x, but seems not to be part of JFX 2.x. Internally, a translation to and from `com.sun.javafx.geom.*` is used which seems to be 98% compatible with standard `java.awt.geom.*`, so an adaptation would be easy.

**Edit:** [My backport](https://github.com/Sciss/ShapeInterpolator) from JFX to Java2D works.